# In AutoHotKey, can "GroupAdd" only be used at the beginning of a script?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I have a script I've been customizing (below) and am trying to `GroupAdd` multiple web browsers into a group so that a few of my text auto-expands will only apply to those browsers. What I'm finding, however, is that `GroupAdd` only seems to work when it's right near the top of the script. As soon there's a keyboard shortcut in the script, GroupAdd will not work below that.

I thought maybe the keyboard shortcut wasn't getting returned/closed out, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Or can `GroupAdd` only ever be used at the beginning of scripts?

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/EasyWindowDrag_(KDE).htm

Comment: It seems that your command gets "interrupted" by the end of the [autoexecute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). Make sure the `GroupAdd` is properly included in the script flow.

Comment: @Yane Thank you! If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.